# Adding jQuery File Upload to Django Admin

Tags: jquery, django, file-upload, admin

It would be really awesome if I could add [this jQuery file uploader](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) to my Django admin panel, but I'm new to Django and I'm not really sure where to start.  Could someone give me some ideas, and point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Had you tried [django-directupload](https://github.com/cuker/django-directupload)?

Comment: That does look interesting. Have you used it before?  I'm having having trouble getting it to work

Comment: Nope :) What problems do you have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555433/adding-django-directupload-to-django-project

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/sentido/django-ajax-upload-widget

Answer (score 1):

I think this is useful for you. You can  embed it in template file, such as:

```
{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/admin/app/model/uploadjq.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install package django-admin-multiupload, which is added into the django admin a form based on jQuery File Upload, by next command:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload.git
```

Or just clone into your project from https://github.com/gkuhn1/django-admin-multiupload.git
Example of usage:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from gallery.models import Gallery, Image

from multiupload.admin import MultiUploadAdmin

class ImageInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image


class GalleryMultiuploadMixing(object):

    def process_uploaded_file(self, uploaded, gallery, request):
        if gallery:
            image = gallery.images.create(file=uploaded)
        else:
            image = Image.objects.create(file=uploaded, gallery=None)
        return {
            'url': image.file.url,
            'thumbnail_url': image.file.url,
            'id': image.id,
            'name': image.filename
        }

class GalleryAdmin(GalleryMultiuploadMixing, MultiUploadAdmin):
    inlines = [ImageInlineAdmin,]
    multiupload_form = True
    multiupload_list = False

    def delete_file(self, pk, request):
        '''
        Delete an image.
        '''
        obj = get_object_or_404(Image, pk=pk)
        return obj.delete()


class ImageAdmin(GalleryMultiuploadMixing, MultiUploadAdmin):
    multiupload_form = False
    multiupload_list = True


admin.site.register(Gallery, GalleryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Image, ImageAdmin)
```

Where Gallery and Image models are:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Gallery(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Galleries'
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField('File', upload_to='images/')
    gallery = models.ForeignKey('Gallery', related_name='images', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.file.name.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]
```

Comment: django-admin-multiupload worked for me for basic admin support of multiple file upload using the jquery file upload plugin.