# Adding django-directupload to Django project

Tags: django, installation

I was looking to try [django-directupload](https://github.com/cuker/django-directupload#readme) in one of my Django projects, but I'm new to Django and having some trouble with installation. I'm following the installation instructions in the README. I installed django-directupload using `sudo pip install django-directupload`.

Here is my urls.py, which I don't think is right:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from testproject import settings

import directupload
from django.contrib import admin
directupload.admin.patch_admin()
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('testproject.database.views',
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'test_view', name="test_page"),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^directupload/', include(directupload.urls))
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

**Edit:**
So I've gained some insight into overriding admin templates (Thanks ilvar for the link).  I copied and pasted the `contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html` file into the project templates directory in the `/admin/nameofmyapp/` subdirectory, and added `{% load directupload_tags %}{% directupload_head %}` below the rest of the load tags.  When I go to the Django admin I get the exception: `'module' object has no attribute 'admin'` on line 6 of `urls.py`.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note that you should replace `from testproject import settings` with `from django.conf import settings` as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urls.py should look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from testproject import settings

from directupload.admin import patch_admin
from django.contrib import admin
patch_admin()
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('testproject.database.views',
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', 'test_view', name="test_page"),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^directupload/', include(directupload.urls))
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

My imports were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Comment: I'm still getting a "'admin_static' is not a valid tag library" exception after overriding the admin template.  I'll add the additional information to my question.

Comment: What are you trying to do in "EDIT" part? I don't see anything like that in directupload's docs.

Comment: Like it says in installation: Insert the following into the head of your admin/change_form.html template: {% load directupload_tags %}{% directupload_head %}

Comment: So why are you adding `{% load url from future %}{% load admin_urls %}` to `change_list.html` then? :)

Comment: Woops, had a couple of typos in there. Thanks for pointing that out. They are now fixed. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: That should not happen, there really *is* [admin_static](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags) tag library. Check if you have deleted or somehow corrupted it. Do other admin pages work?

Comment: Something must have been corrupted, I updated Django and no longer have that error.  I now get: 'module' object has no attribute 'admin' located in line 6 of urls.py

Comment: Try to debug it, and maybe post other question with proper information. I can't open a debug session here, sorry.